# Is there a way to execute a javascript function at the end of a WebForms event?

Tags: jquery-ui, webforms

I have a screen I am creating to manipulate a document. As part of the web form I have a table of page thumbnails on the left side with controls for the current page in the main portion of the screen. When a thumbnail is clicked an UpdatePanel in the body section is updated with the info for that page.

I have just added the ability to change the order of the pages by dragging the thumbnails up and down. This uses JqueryUI's Sortable feature with a hidden asp:Button to communicate the changes back to the server.

All of that works when used separately. However, when I click a thumbnail to select a page the table that they are in looses the sortable property. I can easily re-establish it using a JavaScript command. But how do I call a Javascript command at the end of the WebForms event?

Answer (score 0):

It is strange that after clicking on a thumbnail the script is broken. But you would have to post some source code and ASPX/ASCX to investigate that.

But it is possible to execute some javascript at the end of a postback. Have a look at this documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/bb398976(v=vs.100)

I think you want to have a look at the 'pageLoaded' or 'endRequest' events, maybe you can call your javascript from there.